# How can I save a dynamically generated module and reimport them from file?

Tags: python, python-module

I have an application that dynamically generates a lot of Python modules with class factories to eliminate a lot of redundant boilerplate that makes the code hard to debug across similar implementations and it works well except that the dynamic generation of the classes across the modules (hundreds of them) takes more time to load than simply importing from a file.  So I would like to find a way to save the modules to a file after generation (unless reset) then load from those files to cut down on bootstrap time for the platform.

Does anyone know how I can save/export auto-generated Python modules to a file for re-import later.  I already know that pickling and exporting as a JSON object won't work because they make use of thread locks and other dynamic state variables and the classes must be defined before they can be pickled.  I need to save the actual class definitions, not instances.  The classes are defined with the `type()` function.

If you have ideas of knowledge on how to do this I would really appreciate your input.

Comment: Can you post a small sample of your code that demonstrates the issue that you are having? Did you look at the standard library `ast`? How different is your generated code?

Comment: This sounds like a probable [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) to me. *Why* do you think you need to do things this way? Python has metaclasses, so you likely don't need to create the classes by calling `type()`.

Comment: @VirtualScooter The code is actually bigger than I can post here but the project in question is open source and the link is https://github.com/zimagi/zimagi.  I have index libraries that I use to generate Django models,  application commands, and plugin/providers based on YAML specifications.  The end goal is to create a platform that builds itself based on architectural configuration that is merged together from multiple application modules that are combined to create a unified code base.  I have not seen a way to do what I am trying to do with the AST library but I may have missed something.

Comment: @martineau I know all about metaclasses and metaprogramming in general and use extensively but these did not meet the general needs that I had.  I assure you I am not asking an XY problem.  I have thought about what I am doing quite a bit and it didn't start off with this architecture but I am building a platform where a lot of the code is built from YAML specifications, and metaclasses did not help with this because that still involves creating the classes that extend them by hand (and that was not the goal).  I do use metaclasses and metaprogramming in the platform where it makes sense.

Comment: For anyone who reads this, I really do want to know exactly about what I asked.  I'm not looking for a change of direction.

Comment: Seems to me that if you can't save source code that corresponding to the things being dynamically created, then the only alternative is to save the information used to create them, so that *it* could later be reused to recreate them.

Comment: IMO you would be much more likely to get an answer if you posted a [mre] (MRE).

Comment: I guess I was thinking this was a pretty generic question that was self explanatory.  This does not really have to do with the underlying algorithms but tips on saving / exporting dynamically created modules.  Since I already have the information you speak of @martineau saved in YAML files, I've already got that covered.  What exactly would make this generic question easier to understand?

Comment: Think about it as if you were caching an autogenerated Python module instead of running through the type() build process each time

Comment: I "get" what you're doing, which is what I meant about saving the info that determines the arguments which are passed to `type()`. Dynamically creating or auto-generating modules is very uncommon — so want you want to do with them is an equally uncommon need — and likely a big factor in the lack of response you're getting or are going to get.

Comment: Yeah, I agree.  I have not really seen this approach used in any other Python software project I have looked at or used (which have been a lot), and have not found any documentation on the subject.  And all works fine except for a few seconds longer on bootstrap than I would like when launching the program from the CLI (the performance hit is acceptable when launching the API).  I was always fascinated by the philosophy of Lisp, where the code writes code, and have been trying to emulate that in Python.  I just posted here in case anyone had any knowledge but I can see that is unlikely.

Comment: I found myself writing Python code that generates code also, and am wondering about solutions. Specifically I'm wondering about dumping the generated python code into files. Today I'm generating a handful of dataclasses as well as methods for a Repository class for a HTTP API wrapper... I plan to add the remaining 95% of the dataclasses soon -- I wonder if my code will soon take several seconds to generate all that code...

Answer (score 0):

You’re basically asking how to write a **compiler** whose input is a module **object** and whose output is a `.pyc` file.  (One plausible strategy is of course to generate a `.py` and then byte-compile that in the usual fashion; the following could even be adapted to do so.)  It’s fairly easy to do this for simple cases: the `.pyc` format is [very simple](https://nedbatchelder.com/blog/200804/the_structure_of_pyc_files.html) (but note the comments there), and the `marshal` module does all of the heavy lifting for it.  One point of warning that might be obvious: if you’ve already evaluated, say, `os.getcwd()` when you *generate* the code, that’s not at all the same as evaluating it when *loading* it in a new process.

The “only” other task is constructing the **code** objects for the module and each class: this requires concatenating a large number of boring values from the `dis` module, and will fail if any object encountered is non-trivial.  These might be global/static variables/constants or default argument values: if you can alter your generator to produce modules **directly**, you can probably wrap all of these (along with anything else you want to defer) in function calls by *compiling* something like

```
my_global=(lambda: open(os.devnull,'w'))()
```

so that you actually emit the function and then a call to it.  If you can’t so alter it, you’ll have to have rules to recognize values that need to be constructed in this fashion so that you can **replace** them with such calls.

Another detail that may be important is **closures**: if your generator uses local functions/classes, you’ll need to create the cell objects, perhaps via “fake” closures of your own:

```
def cell(x): return (lambda: x).__closure__[0]
```